# Encode - Decode Json issue

Tags: javascript, php, json

I try to connect a chrome extension with php file with XMLHttpRequest.

Work fine, but I can use  JSON.parse for decode Json.

Js file:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                client.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (client.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                            var j = client.responseText;

                        console.log(j);

                            }
                }
                client.open("GET", "http://localhost/extencio/index.php?"+o, true);

                client.send();
```

In php file I return an object with:

```
echo json_encode($oFinal);
```

The result of **console.log(j);** is:

{"textoDonde":"nombre","value":"getText","donde":"name"}{"textoDonde":"apellido","value":"getText","donde":"name"}{"textoDonde":"sexo","value":"TyPE no detectoado","donde":"name"}
{"textoDonde":"sexo","value":"TyPE no detectoado","donde":"name"}

I change this line in js file for decode:

```
var j = JSON.parse(client.responseText);
```

But have other error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {client.onreadystatechange @ popup.js:66
VM71:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {client.onreadystatechange @ popup.js:66

66 is the "var j" line.

Comment: One single `console.log` is outputting multiple JSON objects?! Are you `echo json_encode`ing in a loop? Then you're not sending valid JSON! Send an `[]` array if you want to send multiple values.

Comment: You should add those objects into a PHP array. Then output the JSON enconding of it's array.

Comment: @Phyron you should post your PHP code here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON output is invalid. You have several objects in your output. Do you want an array of objects? Try this:

```
[{"textoDonde":"nombre","value":"getText","donde":"name"},{"textoDonde":"apellido","value":"getText","donde":"name"},{"textoDonde":"sexo","value":"TyPE no detectoado","donde":"name"},{"textoDonde":"sexo","value":"TyPE no detectoado","donde":"name"}]
```

Run you JSON through a linter like http://jsonlint.com/ to see if its valid.